# SSAS MDX Calculation for SUM(DISTINCT COUNT)

Tags: ssas, mdx

Just to give you an overview I am very new at SSAS cubes and MDX Calculations in general.  I'm currently having a hard time grasping the concept of querying an OLAP Cube.

So say I have a Movement Dimension with a unique key MovementID.  I'm trying to create a calculation in SSAS that counts The total different MovementIDs in this dimension.  So a few questions

1. Can I create this using the New Measure option in SSAS?  It throws me an error if there is a MovementID in the dimension that is not present in my fact table so I'm trying to instead do this in MDX Calculation.  Is my understanding here correct?
2. How do I make this script in MDX SSAS Calculation?  The SQL equivalent should simply be **SELECT COUNT(PFNo) FROM Dim_Movement**.  I know that the OLAP query works on axes rather than traditional table format.  So how can I achieve a simple DISTINCT COUNT of a column in MDX script?
3. If I were to make the script to compute the SUM of the DISTINCT COUNT of the column instead.  What would the script look like?

Thanks!

Comment: why do you need to know how many rows are in your dimension?You might have an XY problem....

Comment: It's going to be used to compute the ratio between how many Movements have Escorts vs how many total movements are there.  The dimension has the total number of Movements.  The only movements in the fact table are the ones with escorts.  Not sure if this is incorrect design wise but is it not normal to count number of rows in dimensions?

Comment: "The dimension has the total number of Movements. " - huh? That seems like a Fact table concern?